# "Если ..., суть такая" - верный ли оборот?

Tags: придаточное-предложение

"Если вы раньше не играли в настольные ролевые игры (НРИ), суть такая: вы собираетесь с друзьями, чтобы создать интерактивную историю о персонажах, которых сами же и придумаете."

Мне режет глаза конструкция "Если... то суть такая". Думаю, это правильнее написать "если... то их суть такова". Что скажете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Верный оборот (если это оборот).

Это параллельно существующие конструкции: суть такая (какая?) = суть такова (какова?).

P. S. По поводу грамматики. Я редактор, и это предложение читаю так:

*Если вы раньше не играли в настольные ролевые игры,* <то спешим вам сообщить, что> *суть такая...*

Зачем громоздить необязательные слова?

Comment: Галина, скажите, а есть примеры применения подобных конструкций в письменных текстах? В разговорном варианте смысл фразы понятен (устная речь значительно отличается от письма, там главное - чтобы тебя поняли, любые пропуски допускаются), но какова грамматика подобных предложений?

Comment: Это речь художественной литературы, не официоза. В конкретном тесте (речь про игры) - это слегка такое заигрывание с потенциальным игроком. Правки не требует. И вопрос о *такая - такова.*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Полностью согласен с Вашей трактовкой, Галина. "Суть такая" здесь относится не к "сути игр" и потому не требует грамматического согласования с "играми"; это суть того, что хотят донести до собеседника (суть такая = вот главное, что вам нужно знать).

Comment: Да ерунда это все. Там просто пропущено смысловое "то". См. мой ответ.

Comment: А "Редактор" - это накакание автору за все грехи его предков до седьмого колена. По мне так они все снобы профессиональные, особенно если из корректоров вышли. Плохо не то, что они "на страже **буквы** закона" стоят, плохо то, что они смысла написанного не понимают, но править лезут исключительно "под себя".

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае от главного предложения к придаточному с союзом *если* невозможно задать вопрос *ПРИ КАКОМ УСЛОВИИ?* *Ср.: Суть такая ПРИ КАКОМ УСЛОВИИ?* Это говорит о том, что предложение построено неверно. Ваш вариант правки тоже неудачен.

***Если вы раньше не играли в настольные ролевые игры (НРИ), разъясняем суть предлагаемой нами игры...***  Ср.: *Разъясняем (ПРИ КАКОМ УСЛОВИИ?), если не играли.* Возможен такой вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Странную грамматику вы тут навели... А по мне - так обычный эллипсис.

*Если вы раньше не играли в настольные ролевые игры (НРИ), **[то расскажу:/то знайте:]** суть такая: вы собираетесь с друзьями, чтобы создать интерактивную историю о персонажах, которых сами же и придумаете."*

Думаю, все объясняет. Так и только так всегда подобные обороты и воспринимал. Остальное - от лукавого. У Екатерины хоть какая-то попытка всё объяснить логикой, хотя тоже может быть подвергнуто остракизму, ибо не закончено.

Но про "суть", которая "если", это выше моих серых клеток.

Короче, как разговорный вариант - нормально. В письменно-деловом и прочих неразговорных стилях - лучше не надо.

Answer (score 1):

Да, Екатерина права, грамматику предложения (СПП с придаточным условным)  **следует как-то исправить**. Можно предложить следующий вариант:

Если вы раньше не играли в настольные ролевые игры (НРИ), вам следует ознакомиться с их правилами, которые заключаются в следующем:  вы собираетесь с друзьями, чтобы создать интерактивную историю о персонажах, которых сами же и придумаете."